# How to get real list of object properties and its values

Tags: .net, reflection

I have className in string variable and its Id:

```
string className = "Solution.TestClass"
long id = 1;
```

I'm using nHibernate to get entity from DB by its type and ID and its works but the returned object is has object type.

```
Type t = Type.GetType(className);
var result = context.Get(t, id);
```

Now I need to get values of properties from result object. Is there any way to do this by reflection? All I got is the class name and assembly. When I try to get property which belongs to class "TestClass" I get an error because it doesn't belong to "object" type.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to _get property which belongs to class "TestClass"_ ?

Comment: var propertyValue = result.GetType().GetProperty("TestProperty").GetValue(result);

Comment: why not `t.GetProperty("TestProperty").GetValue(result)` ?